# How to create a histogram of 2D arrays in ipython

Tags: python, ipython

I have use the random number generator create a 1000*1000 2d arrays. How can i create a histogram of those 2D arrays?

```
s1=np.random.rand(1000,1000)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install and use `matplotlib`.  Your code will look something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s1=np.random.rand(1000,1000)
plt.hist(s1)
```

`matplotlib` gives you a ton of useful options, you can read more about them [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist).